# Xelement converting special characters to strings

Tags: c#, xelement

The below `XElement` converts the special character "&" to "`&amp;`".

```
XElement newElement = new XElement("testting", "wow&testvalue");
```

I want it to be the "&" not `&amp;`.

Comment: `&` is a special character in XML.  You need to wrap the text in a CDATA block to preserve it as `&` - `<![CDATA[wow&testvalue]]>`.

Comment: for '&' converting to"amp". similarly for '<,>' to "lt" and "gt" special characters

Comment: I agree with @Tim. `<![CDATA[]]>` works most of the time.

Answer (score 3):

> I want it to be the "&" not &.

Then it would be invalid XML. Why do you want invalid XML?

LINQ to XML is expressing the text you've requested in valid XML. That's what it's meant to do. If you ask for the text of the element later (through this or any other decent XML API) you'll get back `wow&testvalue`.

As Tim says, you *could* use a CDATA section:

```
var element = new XElement("testing", new XCData("wow&testvalue"));
```

But you can't tell LINQ to XML not to escape what it needs to escape...

Comment: actually we are saving the "wow&testvalue" in database. When i tried the above expression it saves as "[CDATA[wow&testvalue]]". I want to save "wow&testvalue". How do i replace that?

Comment: @user2392525: Well then you're not saving the XML - or shouldn't be. It sounds like you should be providing a *lot* more information in the question; I've provided the best answer I can based on the very limited context you've provided.